# Pipes and fork() - How to write an array of int throught a pipe in C?

Tags: c, arrays, fork, pipe

I'm triying to learn pipes in C and I'm stuck. I tried many things but I can't get the correct output.

Next program should show:
123

But Its output is always direction (unless I think):

-1845296639

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i;
    int buff[4];
    int f[2];

    if(pipe(f) == -1)
        perror("pipe");

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){ 

        int val = i+1;
        switch(fork()){
            case -1:
                perror("fork");
                break;
            case 0:
                close(f[0]);
                write(f[1], &val, 1);
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    close(f[1]);

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        wait(NULL);

    read(f[0], buff, i);
    printf("%d", *buff);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You are writing a single byte through the pipe — you want to write `sizeof(int)` bytes. The same for reading.

Comment: do you need to use a pipe? `fork`ed processes share pointers, so if you malloc the space in advance it will be available to both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipes send *bytes* from one place to another. So you need to precisely specify what *bytes* you are going to send. Then make sure your sending code sends precisely those bytes and your receiving code expects precisely those bytes.

If you want it to work without having to do things the right way, do this:

Sender:

```
write(f[1], &val, sizeof(int));
```

Receiver:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  read(f[0], &buf[i], sizeof(int));
```

Note also `printf("%d", *buff);` prints the first element in the array (element zero).

Do not change the receiving code to `read(f[0], buf, 3 * sizeof(int));`. Your `write` is not atomic (because you call `write` three times) so you can't expect your `read` to be.

Answer (score 1):

The bit pattern of `-1845296639` is `0x92030201`, assuming 32-bit two's complement `int`s.

So you get one byte of garbage from using the uninitialised buffer, and the three bytes written by the `fork`ed children.

Presumably, your platform is little-endian, and that would mean that in memory, the bytes are

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x92
```

so the written bytes arrived in order, as  desired, although expecting `read(...,...,3)` to read three bytes after three children have written one byte each to the pipe is daring.